# How can I modify 'askstring' dialog box s size in Tkinter? in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter.commondialog
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Frame, Label, PhotoImage, Button, simpledialog
import form
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import json

from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog
from tkinter import commondialog  



class My_Class():
    def__init__(self):
        self.my_list=["a"]

     def my_function(self):

         list=["s","ss","df"]
        for i in list:
            q=tkinter.simpledialog.askstring(text="",prompt=i)
```

when I searched related questions I did not see an answer for Python, yes Django, android available but how can we implement `askstring` dialog box?
a related function is a body() I cannot find a way to use it and resize the dialog box.

Comment: what exactly is this instruction "return widget that should have initial focus."? still it did not work. My three days is only about this problem. :(

Comment: that is exactly what it says, for example, you have an entry widget `entry = Entry(master)` and `entry.pack()` or sth and you want that the keyboard focus is on that specific entry widget once the dialog is shown so you can `return entry` at the end of the function and it will set focus to that entry upon opening, it is not necessary to use that btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the width and height of `Dialog` you can do this: call `.geometry` in the `body` method:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog


class MyDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title=None, width=300, height=200):
        # all variables should be initialized before calling 
        # `super` because it calls .wait_window
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(parent, title)

    def body(self, master):
        self.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

MyDialog(root)
```

Comment: sorry but I need to ask that (I am not comfortable using OOP) How can I use this code inside my class? Thank you.

Comment: @ugur what do you mean? classes are a part of OOP (so your question about using code in a class and the statement of not being comfortable with OOP is contradictory), and what is your class? the code you have provided is not python and you have tagged python and there is no other way to write this than I have shown, you are supposed to inherit from `Dialog` and override its methods to add your own functionality

Comment: I have changed my question in order to be more clear. Could you show your solution on my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to change the geometry of `tkinter.simpledialog.ask[string, integer, float]` then it has to be done in a way like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring, Dialog


def change_geometry():
    widget = root.winfo_children()[-1]
    if isinstance(widget, Dialog):
        widget.geometry('500x500')


def show_dialog():
    root.after(10, change_geometry)
    return askstring('Title', 'prompt', parent=root)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

Button(root, text='ask string', command=show_dialog).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Have to schedule a call after opening the dialog to a function that will get the children of the root window and as the dialog's parent is set as root (also automatically but better be explicit) then it will also appear in that list, it should be the last one but there is a check in place to check if it actually is an instance of `Dialog` (since `Dialog` is somewhere up the inheritance chain and it inherits from `Toplevel` which has the `.geometry` method which allows to change the geometry of the dialog).

Comment: This only creates a new window but the dialog box remains the same.  In the current situation, we cannot change the size of the dialog box because parameters are limited. title, prompt are available  I need to add width and height in order to make the desired changes in Tkinter 'askstring' dialog box. So How can we modify the box?

Comment: is it possible to read title ? I want to fix dialog box at one place and read whole title. For example: "This massage is too long to read after awhile" shows on the box as "This mas...."

Comment: @ugur, yes by changing geometry of the window as I have shown in my answer, right now I don't have access to my computer so I can't help much, will be back at monday

Comment: thank you, I am currently trying out your solution.

Comment: my 'tk.messagebox.askstring(title=,prompt=)' is working inside an inner function which is located inside a class. So I use it in order for calculation. For instance:                          "What is your name? if answer == string:  member_numbers=+1. So I do not know how to insert your function inside my inner function or how to use it inside my code structure?

Comment: @ugur your question is confusing, what do you mean by `if answer == string`? what calculations? with a string type? what do you want to do? please provide a proper [mre] and explanation of what you want to achieve in your question, otherwise this should be easily achievable for you